# Unity laggy camera on webgl

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a problem with camera movement that is laggy only when I upload the webgl build on itch.io. Otherwise the pc build and while I'm testing in editor, the camera doesn't have any lag.

```
private void LateUpdate()
    {
            Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.position, _cameraPosToGo, _cameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: Consider caching `Camera.main` into variable in `Start()` or `Awake()` and use that variable in `LateUpdate()`

Comment: I saved the camera.main on awake and used the variable, nothing improved

Comment: Can you clarify “laggy”, e.g. is it falling behind or stuttering? If stuttering might you just be seeing the effects of a low framerate? If falling behind, is the speed of the object it’s following also multiplied by deltatime?